# GUI testing coverage

Tags: user-interface, testing

I have two questions. My first question is: Do applications exist which measure the coverage of GUI testing for web applications (not code, but the coverage of GUI components on web page)?

My second question is:
Is GUI testing with Selenium for example necessary if we have tests for javascript as well?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can write your custom application to find all dom elements using http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp, store this in some place and after completing your test automation framework run this utility to make sure that none of the elements are missing.
2. GUI test is required to make sure that all your integration points b/w several backend API are working. Also we will be sure that non of the UI elements are break over UI and all your business use cases are working as expected. Mostly UI testing is done for Acceptance Testing and we can show to the customer that all there use cases are working as expected. Later in the next release you can make sure that you are not breaking any UI code. UI testing gives us confidence while releasing to end users.